# Split/Break highest row table on more pages with mPDF

Tags: mpdf

I'm trying to split/break highest row table on more pages, do you know the way?

note: I already open a new discussion on the mPDF [forum](http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/1484/splitbreak-row-table-on-more-pages)